# Parsing Data from Email - I Require the Best Solution for Extracting an Unknown Number of Elements

Tags: arrays, email, parsing, variables, power-automate

I have also posed this on the Power Automate community forums in hope of finding the best solution to my issue, even if I don't get a defined answer, I would happily take any suggestions on how to overcome my issue.

I currently have a Power Automate flow which involves converting the body of an email to text (HTML-to-text), converting this text into an array of lines and then extracting only the relevant values using the corresponding line from the array. The extracted values are then added into an Excel table where a new row is added each time. For example an email may contain:

Name: Full Name1

Age: 20

Location: South

Name: FullName2

Age: 21

Location: North

This converted into an array may look like so:

[1] Name:

[2] Full Name1

[3] Age

[4] 20

[5] Location:

[6] South

[7] Name:

[8] Full Name2

[9] Age

[10] 21

[11] Location:

[12] North

The values pulled from the above email would be [2]. [4]. [6]. [8]. [10] and [12].

The problem I'm having is an email may contain only one set of data, or potentially 10 sets of data - in circumstances where only one set of data is received, the current array would fail to run or document unnecessary values from lines that are irrelevant. Or on the flipside of this, may not account for lines [14] and beyond if more than 2 sets of data are received. The format of each email will always be the same, but the amount of text, and therefore amount of required data and number of lines will always vary from one email to another. This is due to me manipulating an email being sent from an external source where I have no power on restricting one set of data per email etc.

It's obvious the way I'm going around this is incorrect, seemingly trying to create an array for an unknown number of elements which can vary from one email to another, but I'd appreciate anyone guiding me in the right lines on how to manage the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the text with the new line character (0A). After that you can use a check for items which start with Age: in a Filter Array action.

Below is an example

```
split(outputs('Compose'), decodeUriComponent('%0A'))
```

For the where you can use

```
item()
```

Starts with Age:

[image]

This would be the output of a test run:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you reply, this is similar to what i'm looking for however worded by original post quite poor. There is one line for First Name, then the name is on the line below. Then 'Age' on the line below that, with the numbered age value below that etc. I'm looking at trying to create an array that utilises chunk() but can't work out how to grab the value per line below

Comment: In your case you could probably use the body of the Filter Array output and break it up in chunks of 2 items? `chunk(body('Filter_Array'), 2)`